# How to check all threads are free in fixed thread pool?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

I need to check all threads free in fixed thread pool. depends on that i'll do some other task with thread... is there any way to find it?

Comment: GetAvailableThreads minus GetMaxThreads

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the pool as a stack.

When you need a thread, pop it from the stack and use it.

When you are done with the thread, push it back to the stack.

If the stack is empty then block until a thread is available.

I would recommend though, to use a library (in the language that you use) that creates/manages the thread pool instead of creating your own.